# Can't connect to phppgadmin/

Tags: sql, linux, apache, postgresql, debian

I have installed php5, apache2, postgresql, phppgadmin... from the repo on my ovh server,
and configured conf.d/phppgadmin for my Ip adress.

```
order deny,allow
# deny from all
allow from 192.168.0.47 ::1/128
# allow from all
```

And when I go to my-server/phppgadmin/ and try to connect myself with the default "postgres" login, without password and with "root" password, I always get the fail connexion message... (Échec de la connexion)

Yet, I set the line

```
$conf['extra_login_security'] = false
```

in the /etc/phppgadmin/config.inc.php file, to false, but nothing change...

I also create a new user in console:

```
su postgres
createuser myuser
```

and set a password:

```
psql template1
ALTER USER myuser password 'mypassword'
```

and reboot Postgresql:

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

But I still can't connect in phppgadmin/ !

Big thanks for help, I don't know what's wrong...

Answer (score 1):

First find file: `pg_hba.conf` and edit/add. See: "0.0.0.0/0", the responsibility is yours .

releasing everything can be risky :
0.0.0.0/0 will allow all and all .

"local" is for Unix domain socket connections only

```
local all all trust
```

IPv4 local connections:

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust
```

IPv6 local connections:

```
host all all ::1/128 trust
```

Second,

2.1) file:  `/etc/phppgadmin/config.inc.php` change to `$conf['extra_login_security'] = false`

2.2)

If login *for UNIX domain socket.* don't change: `/etc/phppgadmin/config.inc.php` and execute command:  `usermod -a -G postgres apache`

If not login _for UNIX domain socket._change it to `$conf['servers'][0]['host'] = 'localhost';`

Finally restart Apache and Postgres and it will work. Access with

```
user:postgres
pass: NOTHING, no pass.
```

Once logged in, change the User and Password or the User Add user / password you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the phppgadmin login page then it's not a problem with your apache config. Since you get a connection error message I would guess that your Apache is trying to reach the Postgres server at the wrong address.

You have probably set up the database in phppgadmin config using the public IP, try the loopback one (127.0.0.1).